# Can OmniThreadLibrary be used in a Delphi Windows Service?

Tags: delphi, omnithreadlibrary

OmniThreadLibrary is a very interesting library. However, I'm worried about its use in a Windows Service.

All tests from repository are Forms based. And most of them use (implicitly or explicitly) a message-based infrastructure (via TOmniEventMonitor).

I made a small DUnit test and it never worked as expected. It only started to work after I put Application.ProcessMessages in several key places of my code. (!)

The same tests worked correctly in a Forms application. But never in a continuous procedure code like a DUnit test.

I'm missing something? How could I use OmniThreadLibrary in a Windows Service? or in a continuous procedure without spreading Application.ProcessMessages in several points?

Comment: From my own experience it works just fine

Comment: It's  shame nobody referred to this question since a long time...

Answer (score 0):

OmniThreadLibrary in a service works just fine. There's an [example](https://github.com/gabr42/OmniThreadLibrary/tree/master/tests/63_Service) in the repo showing that.